# &nbsp character not displaying correctly in Java

Tags: java, formatting, whitespace, spacing

I have tried "`&nbsp;&nbsp;`" to display two spaces in a standard output Java String.  Trying `System.out.println("__");`   <---- (two spaces, but, obviously, it trims it down to one space, hence the underscore)

I imagine there is a way to escape the `&nbsp;`, but I can not figure it out nor find help online.  Searching for it is ironic because a lot of literal `&nbsp;&nbsp;`   show up.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

```
for (int j = 0; j < COLUMNS; j++)
  if (j < 10){
    r += "__";
  }
```

produces 10 spaces, not 20 like expected when printed

sorry I am still new at formatting here

Comment: Is COLUMNS == 10?  Otherwise, that should work just fine.

Comment: COLUMNS = 15.  That's what I don't get.  I'll have to debug and pay attention.  Thanks for the help thus far everyone.

Comment: r is not truncated in any way, and the two spaces ALWAYS output as one.  Since this is not my code, I feel obligated at this point to raise this issue with the developer that it belongs to.  Thanks for everyone's help trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&nbsp;` is an HTML-specific encoding.

You were right first time - the Java string that corresponds to two spaces is simply two space characters, e.g.

```
String s = "  ";
```

The println() call that you tried *ought* to have worked.  What did you do that led you to believe it was trimmed down to a single space?  I think your problem is elsewhere...

EDIT:

Based on your code snippet - is `COLUMNS` 5, by any chance? :-)

EDIT AGAIN:

OK, if COLUMNS is 15 then this code will result in `r` having twenty spaces appended to it.  If you want to be really sure you can either step through in a debugger or put a logging statement above the `r +=` line to see for sure how many times the statement is called.

Also have a look at how `r` is used later on before its output is printed to the place you're inspecting; perhaps its value is truncated at some point, either explicitly in Java or perhaps even implicitly (such as being stored in a database column that's 10 characters too narrow before being retrieved and displayed later).

Answer (score 6):

If you want a non-breaking space in your string, for whatever reason, you have to use the Unicode literal:

```
System.out.println("banana\u00A0phone");
```

Comment: You don't have to use the unicode literal if your source code character encoding contains a code point for NBSP (and most character encodings does). You can simply use it as any other character directly in the string literal: "banana phone" (no idea how this is actually rendered by SO)

Comment: SO replaced it with a regular space, but as I said, it is possible to use NBSP in Java code.

Comment: You *should* use the unicode literal, so that your intentions regarding an invisible distinction will be made clear.

Comment: Are you also using the Unicode literal \u006f instead of 'o' to distinguish it from 'о'?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use &nbsp in Java. `System.out.print("  ");` should do the trick. Try something like:

```
System.out.print("This is the a string before spaces" + "  " + "this is a string after spaces");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a non-breaking space by holding the Alt key and typing 0160 on the number pad.